# Nested case statements within switch

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

So I've been struggling with this for a while now and I do not understand why this works.

```
int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        switch(i) {
            case 1: case 4: case 7: sum++;
            default: continue;
            case 5: break;
        }
        break;
    }

    printf("%d", sum);
}
```

Output:

```
2
```

I wasn't able to find any information on nested case statements anywhere else.

Comment: ‘Fallthrough’ is the keyword for which to search. (They're not really ‘nested’, indeed they're often written *underneath* one another.)

Comment: aside: get in the habit of `break`ing every `case`. while your `continue` means you don't "need" it, you can end up with something way more unexpected than case fall-through if you omit it... The loop increments `sum` on `i=1` and `i=4`, and stops on `i=5`...  `0+1+1 == 2`. if you don't need conditional flow, but optionally want conditional values, a LUT is faster and simpler: `sum=0; for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) sum+={1:1,4:2,7:3}[i]||0;`

Comment: This is the prefect opportunity to compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch(i) {
    case 1: case 4: case 7: sum++;
    default: continue;
    case 5: break;
}
```

The above can be equivalently rewritten as

```
switch(i) {
    case 1:
    case 4:
    case 7: sum++;
    default: continue;
    case 5: break;
}
```

Cases `1`, and `4` exhibit a fall through. Meaning that execution proceeds into the next case statement. Ultimately resulting in all three cases executing the same code.

The interesting part to note, is that `default` is also a valid label. And it doesn't have to appear last! If you remove the `continue` statement, the execution will continue from `default` into `case 5` and the loop will end when `i` is `2`.

Comment: I don't know why, but having `default:` anywhere else but at the end really gives me the creeps... haha.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl Years of seeing it at the end will do that to you :) Although when I learned C initially I often wondered why the default case isn't at the top.

Comment: I guess so. Well now that you say it, it would actually not be that weird to have it there. However, for me it's easier reading it with default at the end, since I see it as a _"if all fails"_ case as in "it has gone through all cases, didn't match any, so now we are here". I guess it all comes down to personal preference.  :)

Answer (score 1):

They are not nested. They are just three labels for the same `sum++;` instruction.

The code jumps there in case of `i==1` and `i==4`, hence `sum` becomes `2`. Values 0, 2 and 3 cause the `switch` to jump do the `default` label, which is a `continue;` instruction, causing the loop to make next iteration.

On `i==5` the switch is terminated with the inner `break;` instruction and execution proceeds to the `break` following the `switch(i){...}`. That causes a loop termination, so the `i` variable never reaches the value 7, and `sum` remains 2.